# Expected value of order statistics from uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, estimation, order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n\sim U[0,1]$

We have to show that:

1. $$\mathbf{E}[X_{(k)}^r] =\frac{n!\Gamma(r+k)\ }{(r-1)!\Gamma(n+k+1)} $$

2.If $r$ is integer then: $$\mathbf{E}[X_{(k)}^r] = \frac{ {r+k-1 \choose r}}{ {n+r \choose r}}$$

My proof for 1.

$$\mathbf{E}[X_{(k)}^r] = \int_0^1 x^rf(x) \,dx= \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} \int_0^1 x^r[F(x)]^{k-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-k}f(x)dx  $$
$$ = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\int_0^1 x^rx^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k}dx $$

$$ =\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\beta(k+r,n-k+1)=\frac{n!\Gamma(r+k)\Gamma(n-k+1)}{(k-1)!(n-k)!\Gamma(n+k+1)}=\frac{n!\Gamma(r+k)\ (n-k)(n-k-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-k)!\Gamma(n+k+1)} = \frac{n!\Gamma(r+k)\ }{(k-1)!\Gamma(n+r+1)}$$

but I got stuck to prove 2, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get Equation $2$ from Equation $1$, because they are not the same.  You've mixed up your $r$ and $k$.  Notice how in your proof of Equation $1$, you wrote

$$\operatorname{E}[X_{(k)}^r] = \int_{x=0}^1 x^{\color{red}{k}} f_{X_{(k)}}(x) \, dx.$$  This is clearly wrong, because you wrote an exponent of $r$ on the left hand side, but the exponent on the right hand side is $k$.  If you do the computation correctly with $r$ instead, then you will get

$$\operatorname{E}[X_{(k)}^r] = \frac{n! \, \Gamma(r+k)}{(\color{blue}{k}-1)! \, \Gamma(n+\color{blue}{r}+1)}.$$  Then this equation is consistent with Equation $2$ from your original question.

Comment: You right I had mistake but when I also tried to open this and this is what I get $$\mathbf{E}[X_{(k)}^r] = \frac{n!(r+k-1)!\ }{(k-1)!(n+r)(n+r-1)!}$$
And I have no idea how to continue from here

Comment: @Amitn $$\frac{n! \, (r+k-1)!}{(k-1)! \, (n+r)!} = \frac{n! \, r!}{(n+r)!} \cdot \frac{(r+k-1)!}{r! \, (k-1)!}.$$